# Why I can't visit Firebase console using Firefox?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I can't go to Firebase console. I am using Firefox and I am signed in at Firebase. When I click the button named "Get started", it redirects to the following URL

[Google Support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050)

Then according to the URL, I have cleared all the caches, but still it doesn't work.

I am working in a React project, so I need the solution...